# Cross Product Question (Simple Physics)

Tags: vectors, physics, cross-product

A positively charged particle with velocity $v\hat k$ moves
through an unknown (but uniform) magnetic field. The force on the particle is observed to be $\vec F = F_0 (3 \hat{i} + 4\hat j)$. What is the $x$-component of the magnetic field?

The equation we use to solve these problems: $\vec F = q\vec v \times \vec B$

So I know $\vec F$, so I plug that in: $F_0 (3 \hat{i} + 4\hat j) = v\hat k \times \vec B$.

How do I proceed to get the $x$-component?

Note: The answer to this problem is $\frac{4F_0}{qv}$

Comment: Write $\vec{B}=B_x\hat{i}+B_y\hat{j}+B_z\hat{k}$, then solve simultaneous equations. This is much easier than it sounds because the equations decouple, in view of $\hat{j}=\hat{k}\times\hat{i}$ etc.

Comment: So I crossed it with this and got: $qvB_x \hat j - qvB_y \hat i$, but we only focus on things with $\hat j$ in them? So I get $F_0 (4) = vq B_x \rightarrow \frac{4F_0}{ vq}$? Is that the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have that
$$
F_0\,\left(3\hat{i}+4\hat{j}\right) = q\, v\,\hat{k}\times\vec{B},
$$
which means that
$$
F_0\,\left(3\hat{i}+4\hat{j}\right) = q\, v\,\hat{k}\times\left(B_x\hat{i}+B_y\hat{j}+B_z\hat{k}\right),
$$
therefore, recalling that $\hat{k}\times\hat{i}=\hat{j}$ and that the corresponding components of the vectors shall be equal, you get:
$$
4\,F_0\hat{j}=q\,v\,B_x\,\left(\hat{k}\times\hat{i}\right),
$$
i.e.
$$
4\,F_0\hat{j}=q\,v\,B_x\,\hat{j},
$$
hence
$$
4\,F_0=q\,v\,B_x\,
$$
which results precisely in
$$
B_x={4\,F_0\over q\,v}.
$$